# Create a rails 5 plugin that need migrations

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to create a rails 5+ gem that must create a migration as it would have to use a model and save/access data in DB.

My gem has some simple classes I stored in `lib/` but it must use some that should access DB and this is what I don't know how to do.

- `Language` should update itself in a DB
- `Languages` should list all existing Languages and create a new `Language`

Basically in a rails app, I whould create the migrations and models, but I couldn't find tutorials about how to do that, and the rails [doc](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v5.0/plugins.html) did not help me.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at [Rails Engines](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/engines.html).

With an engine you can define generators, models, routes, controllers, etc and hook into a host rails app.

```
# routes
MyCustomGem::Engine.routes.draw do
  resources :languages
end

# controllers
module MyCustomGem
  class LanguagesController < ApplicationController
    ...
  end
end
```

When installing this in a rails app, you'll use

```
$ bin/rails my_custom_gem:install:migrations
```

And that will create the migration in the host app.

Comment: Thanks that looks what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

If you don’t want to copy the migrate file, you can execute migrate directly in the application as follows

```
module MyEngine
  class Engine < ::Rails::Engine
    isolate_namespace MyEngine

    initializer :append_migrations do |app|
      unless app.root.to_s.match root.to_s
        config.paths["db/migrate"].expanded.each do |expanded_path|
          app.config.paths["db/migrate"] << expanded_path
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

When installing this in a rails app

```
 bin/rails db:migrate
```